# MySQL one-to-many join with Group By only returns one observation

Tags: mysql, join

I have a comment table and a tag table. For each comment, there could be multiple tags, or none. I want to join the two so I can get a list of tags for each comment.

CommentTable:

```
+---------+----------+---+
|CommentID|   Title  | ..|
+---------+----------+---+
|   1     |   animals|   |
|   2     |   plants |   |
+---------+----------+---+
```

TagTable:

```
+---------+----------+---+
|  TagID  |CommentID | ..|
+---------+----------+---+
|    5    |     1    |   |
|    6    |     1    |   |
|    7    |     3    |   |
+---------+----------+---+
```

So, a query should return the tags, (5,6) for a commentID == 1 and empty array for CommentID == 2

This is what I have - it only selects the last ID and not multiples:

```
SELECT c.CommentID, c.Title,  t.TagID  FROM Comment as c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Tag as t ON c.CommentID = t.CommentID
        GROUP BY t.TagID
```

Comment: When you make a _GROUP BY_, it must contain minimum all data you selected.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can use [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to turn data in multiple rows into a single delimited string:

```
SELECT    a.CommentID, 
          a.Title,
          GROUP_CONCAT(b.TagID ORDER BY b.TagID) AS tags
FROM      CommentTable a
LEFT JOIN TagTable b ON a.CommentID = b.CommentID
GROUP BY  a.CommentID,
          a.Title
```

In this case, if a comment does not have a corresponding tag, the field would just be NULL.

---

[*SQLFiddle Demo*](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/45f0e/1)

Comment: Awesome...I appreciate the effort. First time I have seen SQLFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
SELECT c.CommentID, c.Title,  t.TagID  FROM Comment as c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN Tag as t ON c.CommentID = t.CommentID
```

edit1: If you want to return only one row per group as per the comment

```
SELECT c.CommentID, c.Title,MAX(t.TagID )
FROM Comment as c
left OUTER JOIN TagTable as t ON c.CommentID = t.CommentID
GROUP BY  c.CommentID, c.Title
```

Comment: MYSQL returns another row to give the complete TagID (5,6) for a CommentID of (1), however the CommentID field is blank in both cases for the example given above.

Comment: yes, but is there a way that I can return only one row for a CommentID == 1 instead of two? Currently, two rows will be returned with each a TagID of 5 and 6 respectively.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I think I am getting closer, although now only TagID of 2 is returned and not both (1,2) in a single row. I suspect this is reflected in using, `MAX` in the `SELECT`

Answer (score -1):

You don't need the group by for this situation:

```
SELECT c.CommentID, c.Title,  t.TagID  FROM Comment as c
LEFT OUTER JOIN Tag as t ON c.CommentID = t.CommentID
```