# Efficient way to query user preferences stored on another table

Tags: php, mysql

I've a two tables, first is the users table where users details are stored and another table where users preferences are stored. I have a page where an admin selects preferences and based on the selected preferences the matched users are returned.

Currently, I've implemented this by selecting all users from users table and using foreach loop querying the preferences table for each use. Please give me ideas how can I improve it. The current approach I've used performs very slow for large number of records.

The preferences are stored as records in preferences table.

Comment: Go Look at SQL JOIN Syntax https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: "The preferences are stored as records in preferences table" you can do a 1 to many join. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807650/mysql-one-to-many-join

Comment: Thanks. I'll have a look at this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JOIN` Syntax is where to Start i don't know your exact Table Layouts so here is an example

```
CREATE TABLE `user`( 
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `Username` VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
    /* ... more columns here */
)
CREATE TABLE `user_prefs`( 
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `bg_color` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    /* ... more columns here */
)
```

then your to join them you can use

```
SELECT * FROM `user` AS U JOIN `user_prefs` AS UP ON U.`id` = UP.`user_id`;
```

Comment: The preferences are not columns but are stored as records in the preferences table.

Answer (score 1):

You can setup one query to pull the information. Assuming id is the same in both tables.

```
SELECT * FROM users, user_prefs WHERE
users.id = user_prefs.id AND
user_prefs.showads = 1 AND
user_prefs.sendemail = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You'll most likely want to look into utilizing a SQL `JOIN`. Assuming your tables are `users` and `preferences`, and `preferences`.`userId` contains a user's `id`, the query would be something like this

```
SELECT * FROM `users` 
  INNER JOIN `preferences` ON `users`.`id` = `preferences`.`userId` 
  WHERE (YOUR CRITERIA);
```