# Select all records from table 1 then select all records from table 2 matching table 1 primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables
1st table which has a primary key c_id.
2nd table has its own primary key and the foreign key c_id (Table 2 can have multiple entry related to table 1)

Im trying query all records from 1st table but also look for all records from 2nd table matching the primary key and echo one of its column to a column on the query.

Here is my Code
Note: Am new to joining tables so the following code is just echoing records from table 1.

```
 <?php
 include_once('connected.php');
 if ($conn->connect_error) {
  die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
  } 

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM files ORDER BY c_id Desc";

   if ($result=mysqli_query($conn,$sql))
 {
 // Return the number of rows in result set
  $rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($result);
 printf("Total = %d \n",$rowcount);
 // Free result set
  mysqli_free_result($result);
  }

  $result = $conn->query($sql);
   if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    //output data of each row
     while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
      echo "<tr> 

                    <td> <b>". $row["c_no"]." </b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_applicants"]. " </b> //this rows should echo all records from 2nd table
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_details"]. " </b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_for"]. " </b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_person"]. " </b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_country"]. "</b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_rdate"]. " </b>
                    <td> <b>". $row["c_galdate"]. "</b>
                    <td> "."<a href=viewfile.php?id=". $row['c_id'] .">Expand</a>". "<br>";

     }
  } else {
  echo " results";
 }
  $conn->close();
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to write a join query from table 1 -> table 2.

Here is a nice resource for [beginners](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-join/)

As a starting point, here is a query that you will probably have to tweak, but put you in the right direction.

```
select columns, you, actually, want from table1 as t1
join table2 as t2
on t1.id = t2.other_id
order by t1.id desc
```

Comment: $sql = "select * from files inner join applicants on files.c_id=applicants.c_id";
I was able to do a join but i want all the records from applicants be echoed to the one coloum of that row. (concatenated or some sort.)
They will be more than one applicants for a file so i want to just show all applicants name on the column of that one row.
I hope i make sense.
Thank you for your help i will continue to read the link you sent.

Comment: I think you are talking about a "one to many" join. Check out this question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11807650/mysql-one-to-many-join-with-group-by-only-returns-one-observation)